# H2 doesn't work as expected when columnType is json

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2

I use H2 for integration tests, using spring with kotlin, jpa + hibernate.
A model in my code has a String field with columnDefinition = "JSON" and this causes a problem with H2.

```
import javax.persistence.Column
...
   @Column(name = "payload", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "JSON")
   var data: String,
```

data field should store any json string. This works well with MySql however with H2 I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

When I debugged I realized that with H2 the json string is converted to an actual string with backslashes
with mysql the actual data in the column:

```
{"a":5}
```

with h2 the actual data in the column:

```
"{\"a\":5}"
```

How can I solve the issue without changing the production code?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate ORM do you use? This issue was fixed in 6.2.0.

Comment: 5.6.9 Unfortunately I cannot change the version of hibernate :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. CustomH2Dialect didn't work. I override the mapping in tests with orm xml.

create `orm_h2.xml` file under `test>resources>META-INF` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <entity class="com.my.package" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <basic name="data">
                <column name="data" nullable="false" column-definition="CLOB"/>
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

in `application-test.properties` set the location of the mapping

```
spring.jpa.mapping-resources=META-INF/orm_h2.xml
```